# Excluding zero values in proportion calculation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, filter, mean

I'm trying to calculate the proportion of seven fields. It is easy to divide the sum of seven fields by seven, but since some fields have zero values, I want to exclude them from the calculation.

For example, if two of the values are zero, I want to divide the sum by five in that row. How can this process be done in the Field Calculator?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this expression:

```
array_mean(
    array_remove_all(
        array("field1", "field2", ...),
        0 -- set here the value to be excluded
        )
    )
```

Comment: Or easier, using `array_mean` function: `array_mean( array_remove_all( array( "field1", "field2", ...),0))`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps somebody will find this PyQGIS solution helpful:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from statistics import mean

def mean_without_zeros(layer_name, list_of_fields, output_field):
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
    fields_names = layer.fields().names()
    
    if not output_field in fields_names:
        new_field = QgsField(output_field, QVariant.Double)
        layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([new_field])
        layer.updateFields()
    
    layer.startEditing()
    
    for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        field_values = [feature.attribute(field.name()) for field in feature.fields() if field.name() in target_fields]
        field_values_no_zeros = filter(lambda x: x > 0, field_values)
    
        feature[output_field] = mean(list(field_values_no_zeros))

        layer.updateFeature(feature)

    layer.commitChanges()
    
    return

mean_without_zeros('data', ["VALUE1", "VALUE2", "VALUE3"], "MEANVAL")
```

[image: result]